# Get link as string on NSTextView clicked() event

Tags: swift, nstextview

I wrote a MyTextView class that inherits from NSTextview.
I override the clicked() function and I want to get the link that is being clicked as a string. My code looks like this:

```
import Cocoa
class MyTextView: NSTextView
{
    override func clicked(onLink: Any, at charIndex: Int) {
        // Get onLink parameter as string
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It took me a while, but at the end I solved it with:

```
override func clicked(onLink: Any, at charIndex: Int) {
    let linkStr = (onLink as AnyObject).description as String
}
```

This piece of code does feel a bit fragile though.

Answer (score 0):

Override clickedonlink instead

https://developer.apple.com/reference/appkit/nstextview/1449497-clickedonlink?language=objc

The first parameter is the link which is of type https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/nslinkattributename?language=objc which will give you the string you need.

Comment: The link you posted in your answer is the Objective-C variant of the Swift method I'm using: https://developer.apple.com/reference/appkit/nstextview/1449497-clicked

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to convert it to a string, try:

```
if let onLinkString = onLink as? String {
   //onLinkString is a string
}
```

Comment: Thanks for trying, but it does't work since the if condition is never met.